# How to format a string fetch from API array into a mix of text and ordered list? (in react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, string, mongodb

I built an autocomplete search bar that render different law sections. Each law sections are fetched from an array of string in Mongodb. Often, there will be an ordered list inside a string. When fetched, they are unformatted. Example:

> 14. The following words have in this code the signification attached to them in this section, unless otherwise apparent from the context: 1. The word "property" includes property real and personal; 2. The words "real property" are coextensive with lands, tenements, and hereditaments; 3. The words "personal property" include money, goods, chattels, things in action, and evidences of debt; 4. The word "month" means a calendar month, unless otherwise expressed; 5. The word "will" includes codicil; 6. The word "section" whenever hereinafter employed refers to a section of this code, unless some other code or statute is expressly mentioned.

I want to be able to dynamically format those strings when rendered like follows:

> 14. The following words have in this code the signification attached to them in this section, unless otherwise apparent from the context:

1. The word "property" includes property real and personal;
2. The words "real property" are coextensive with lands, tenements, and hereditaments;
3. The words "personal property" include money, goods, chattels, things in action, and evidences of debt;
4. The word "month" means a calendar month, unless otherwise expressed;
5. The word "will" includes codicil;
6. The word "section" whenever hereinafter employed refers to a section of this code, unless some other code or statute is expressly mentioned.

How can I achieve that? String function? Regex? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

```js
class Result extends Component {
    state = {};

    render() {
        const value = this.props.laws;
        const { showSearch } = this.props;
        const regex = new RegExp(`\d$(showSearch)`); (failed attempt)

        return (
            <div
                className="container bg-light"
                                >
                <div
                
                    className="container row"
                >
                    {showSearch.length > 1 ? (
                        <div>
                            <h2>{value.law_name}</h2>
                            <br />
                            <h5> {value.section_name}</h5>
                        </div>
                    ) : null}

                    <p>{showSearch}</p> //where the string will show
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Result;
```

```js
class Dashboard extends Component {
    state = {
        laws: [],
        sectionText: [],
        showResult: [],
        suggestions: [],
        suggestionIndex: 0,
        text: "",
        showSearch: "",
        HideShowSearch: false,
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getLaws();
    }
    getLaws = async () => {
        try {
            const { data: laws } = await http.get(urlLaw);
            const sectionText = laws.section_text;
            this.setState({ laws, sectionText });
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex.response && ex.response === 404) alert("error receiving data");
        }
    };

    // text in search bar
    onTextChanged = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        let suggestions = [];
        const { sectionText } = this.state;

        if (value.length > 0) {
            suggestions = sectionText.filter((s) =>
                s.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()),
            );
        }
        this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, text: value }));
    };

    renderSuggestions() {
        const { suggestions, suggestionIndex } = this.state;

        if (suggestions.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul className="">
                {suggestions.map((i, index) => {
                    let className;

                    // Flag the active suggestion with a class
                    if (index === this.state.suggestionIndex) {
                        className = "suggestion-active";
                    }
                    return (
                        <li
                            className={className}
                            onClick={() => this.suggestionSelected(i)}
                            key={i}
                            style={{ background: "#464a47" }}
                        >
                            {i}
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    // input text when click on suggestion
    suggestionSelected(item) {
        this.setState(() => ({
            text: item,
            suggestions: [],
        }));
    }

    onKeyDown = (e, item) => {
        const { sectionText, suggestionIndex, suggestions, text } = this.state;
        const showResult = this.state.laws;
        const showSearch = suggestions[suggestionIndex];

        // when press enter
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setState({
                suggestionIndex: 0,
                suggestions: [],
                text: "",
                showResult,
                sectionText,
                showSearch,
                HideShowSearch: false,
            });

            // when press up arrow
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            if (suggestionIndex === 0) {
                return;
            }
            this.setState({ suggestionIndex: suggestionIndex - 1 });

            // when press down arrow
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            if (suggestionIndex - 1 === suggestions.length) {
                return;
            }
            this.setState({ suggestionIndex: suggestionIndex + 1 });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add newlines in front of the numbers with a regex replacement:

```js
const string = "14. The following words have in this code the signification attached to them in this section, unless otherwise apparent from the context: 1. The word \"property\" includes property real and personal; 2. The words \"real property\" are coextensive with lands, tenements, and hereditaments; 3. The words \"personal property\" include money, goods, chattels, things in action, and evidences of debt; 4. The word \"month\" means a calendar month, unless otherwise expressed; 5. The word \"will\" includes codicil; 6. The word \"section\" whenever hereinafter employed refers to a section of this code, unless some other code or statute is expressly mentioned.";

console.log(string.replace(/\s(\d+\.\s)/g, "\n$1"));
```

Or if you want to format your text directly into a React component, you could do this, assuming it always has a leading paragraph like your example:

```
const LawElement = (props) => {
  const splitLaw = props.string.split(/\s\d+\.\s/);
  return <>
    <p>{ splitLaw[0] }</p>
     <ol>
       { splitLaw.slice(1).map(line => (
          <li>{line}</li>
        )) }
     </ol>
  </>
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
<LawElement string={ yourString } />
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-thunder-ejq6l)

Comment: Yah I like the idea of adding lines. And yes, there's always a leading paragraph as this the way I formatted the JSON files. I will probably do both and modify the regex so it works with an alphabetic list: a) b) c) d).... Thanks a lot that's really helpful!!